# How to add two values into the array using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I want to add the values from the text box into the array, I tried but it only works to add one value, why? If it is possible then how could I achieved it?

This is the code that I tried,

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var x = 0;
  var y = 0;
  var array = Array();

  function addintoarray() {
    array[x] = document.getElementById("cuna").value; //create the array for to add customer name
    array[y] = document.getElementById("cuad").value; //create the array to add customer address
    alert("Customername: " + array[x] + "Added" + "Customeraddress: " + array[y] + "Added"); //display msg
    x++; //count increment to add another one
    y++;
    document.getElementById("cuna").value = "";
    document.getElementById("cuad").value = "";
  }

</script>
```

Table

```
<form method="post">
  <table border="1">
    <tr>
      <td>CustomerName</td>
      <td><input type="text" id="cuna" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>CustomerAddress</td>
      <td><input type="text" id="cuda" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="submit" value="Add" onclick="addintoarray();" />
      </td>
      <td><input type="Submit" value="Display" onclick="displayintoarray" /></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>
```

Comment: because `x` and `y` both points to the same index `0`. You can do `var array= []`, and then `array.push(document.getElementById("cuna").value)` and then `array.push(document.getElementById("cuad").value)`. No need, `x`, `y`..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want the result to be like that :

[[cuna1, cuad1][cuna2, cuad2]]

In this case you should do the following :

```
let arrayToPush = [document.getElementById("cuna").value,document.getElementById("cuad").value]
```

(btw be careful you have a typo in your HTML : "cuda" instead of "cuad")

and then do

```
array.push(arrayToPush)
```

The solution with x= 0 and y=1 will not work because on the second round x will be 1 and y will be 2 and therefor array[x] will overwrite previous value. However they are correct saying you should avoid to use index and rather just push to array.

Comment: good guess with the typo but cuna means customer name and cuad means customer address :)

Comment: then the typo is in the HTML where it says cuda : <td><input type="text" id="cuda" /></td> Anyway both don't fit

Comment: I'm with you, bad variable names

Answer (score 3):

You are initializing both `x` and `y` to `0` so every time you do `array[x] =` or `array[x] =` you are targeting an element at index `0`. If you want to add items you can use the [JavaScript's array.push()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) method.

**Using JavaScript Objects to store values** 
Since I noticed you want to keep adding onto the array you should consider using objects to group your data in your array.
 ` var myArray = Array();

```
  function addintoarray() {
    let name = document.getElementById("cuna").value; 
    let address = document.getElementById("cuad").value;

    myArray.push({'customerName':name,'customerAddress':address})

    alert("Customername: " + name + "Added. " + "Customeraddress: " + address + "Added");

}`
```

Answer (score 2):

What you should do is change the values of the x and y.

```
var x = 0;
var y = 1;
var array = Array();
```

Then this will work.

```
array[x] = document.getElementById("cuna").value; 
array[y] = document.getElementById("cuad").value;
```

But in my opinion you do not need to do like this. You can use array [push](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) method.

```
 array.push(document.getElementById("cuna").value)
 array.push(document.getElementById("cuad").value)
```

Answer (score 0):

You use x,y as index with the same value so replacing each other.
Your assign array[x] and then array[y] which means at initial case

```
array[0]=document.getElementById("cuna").value;
array[0]=document.getElementById("cuad").value;
```

you may use two differnt initial values like x=0, y=1 and still increment values 
x += 2;
y += 2;

instead you may use array prototype to push values

```
array.push(document.getElementById("cuna").value);
array.push(document.getElementById("cuad").value);
```